# WPF: Validating an object at submission

Tags: wpf, validation

I am creating a WPF app using MVVM. The app manages tagged documents, called Notes, similar to blog posts. A Note has a Title, Text and a Tags collection. I want to validate a Note at the time it is submitted for two validation rules:

- The Title can't be empty; and
- The Note must have at least one Tag.

If validation fails, then the Note submission is canceled, the offending control in the UI should get the familair red outline, and a tool tip should explain the error. This all seems pretty straightforward if one wants to validate at the time a WPF control updates its binding source. Just create a custom `ValidationRule` and add it to the `<Binding.ValidationRules>` collection.

My problem is that I want to validate when the Note is submitted, not when controls update their binding sources. I know I can create a custom error message and display it in a MessageBox, but I would much rather use the red outline-tooltip approach--it's less intrusive. I figure there must be some simple way of doing this.

My question is pretty simple: What is the best way of performing on-submission validation in WPF/MVVM? How does my code instruct the UI to show the red error outline when validation fails? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [IDataErrorInfo in conjunction with WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfVABErrorProvider.aspx).

This would make it fairly easy to handle this scenario.  You can just setup the `IDataErrorInfo` information at submission time, which would then cause the "red outline" (or other error theming) to appear.